# Split a text in several parts (Unix)

Tags: bash, unix, awk, grep, cut

I have the next code:

```
mutate {
    add_field => [ "NB_timestamp", "%{SYS_YEAR}/%{SYS_MONTH}/%{SYS_DAY} %{SYS_HOUR}:%{SYS_MIN}:%{SYS_SEC}" ]
   }

if [type] == "batch" {
  if [idx] != "sipp" {
   mutate {
    add_field => [ "idx", "sipp"]
   }
  }
  if [message] == "" {
   drop { }
  }
}

mutate {
    add_field => [ "NB_timestamp", "%{SYS_YEAR}/%{SYS_MONTH}/%{SYS_DAY} %{SYS_HOUR}:%{SYS_MIN}:%{SYS_SEC}" ]
   }
```

I would like to obtain **mutate's part**.That is, in this case I would like get two parts only:

- mutate {
     add_field => [ "NB_timestamp", "%{SYS_YEAR}/%{SYS_MONTH}/%{SYS_DAY}
  %{SYS_HOUR}:%{SYS_MIN}:%{SYS_SEC}" ]    }
- mutate {
     add_field => [ "NB_timestamp", "%{SYS_YEAR}/%{SYS_MONTH}/%{SYS_DAY}
  %{SYS_HOUR}:%{SYS_MIN}:%{SYS_SEC}" ]    }

Not this part:

- mutate {
         add_field => [ "idx", "sipp"]
        }

I have tried with grep,awk and cut. The problem is that these comands (grep,awk and cut) get the *"mutate"* which is inside *"if [type]"* too.

Example:

- sed -n "/mutate\ {/,/}/p" file.txt

Output:

```
mutate {
        add_field => [ "NB_timestamp", "%{SYS_YEAR}/%{SYS_MONTH}/%{SYS_DAY} %{SYS_HOUR}:%{SYS_MIN}:%{SYS_SEC}" ]

mutate {
        add_field => [ "idx", "sipp"]
       }

mutate {
        add_field => [ "NB_timestamp", "%{SYS_YEAR}/%{SYS_MONTH}/%{SYS_DAY} %{SYS_HOUR}:%{SYS_MIN}:%{SYS_SEC}" ]
```

Thanks in advance,

Regards.

Comment: don't make us guess what is **Mutate's part**. Please edit your question to show your required output, given the above code/input? Also, you should include your attempts to resolve your problem, the closest output and any error messages. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks,I have just modified my question.I hope to the question will be good formulated.Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use sed to extract wanted mutate's part:

```
sed -n '/^mutate {/,/   }/p' file.txt
```

The result should be:

`mutate { add_field => [ "NB_timestamp", "%{SYS_YEAR}/%{SYS_MONTH}/%{SYS_DAY} %{SYS_HOUR}:%{SYS_MIN}:%{SYS_SEC}" ] } mutate { add_field => [ "NB_timestamp", "%{SYS_YEAR}/%{SYS_MONTH}/%{SYS_DAY} %{SYS_HOUR}:%{SYS_MIN}:%{SYS_SEC}" ] }`

Answer (score 0):

For your actual example:

```
awk '/}$/{f=0}f;/^mutate/{f=1}' file
```

Results:

```
add_field => [ "NB_timestamp", "%{SYS_YEAR}/%{SYS_MONTH}/%{SYS_DAY} %{SYS_HOUR}:%{SYS_MIN}:%{SYS_SEC}" ]
add_field => [ "NB_timestamp", "%{SYS_YEAR}/%{SYS_MONTH}/%{SYS_DAY} %{SYS_HOUR}:%{SYS_MIN}:%{SYS_SEC}" ]
```

To get all the entity change the flag order:

```
awk '/^mutate/{f=1}f;/}$/{f=0}' file
```

Results:

```
mutate {
    add_field => [ "NB_timestamp", "%{SYS_YEAR}/%{SYS_MONTH}/%{SYS_DAY} %{SYS_HOUR}:%{SYS_MIN}:%{SYS_SEC}" ]
   }
mutate {
    add_field => [ "NB_timestamp", "%{SYS_YEAR}/%{SYS_MONTH}/%{SYS_DAY} %{SYS_HOUR}:%{SYS_MIN}:%{SYS_SEC}" ]
   }
```

Explanation: https://nixtip.wordpress.com/2010/10/12/print-lines-between-two-patterns-the-awk-way/

Comment: Thanks,one question, how could I do to obtain with mutate too?  That is:                                                                                                            mutate {
        add_field => [ "NB_timestamp", "%{SYS_YEAR}/%{SYS_MONTH}/%{SYS_DAY} %{SYS_HOUR}:%{SYS_MIN}:%{SYS_SEC}" ]  }